# Styling autogenerated DataGrid column on validation failure

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a DataGrid filled with instances of a class that exposes a `double` type property. This property is shown into the DataGrid. I want to implement a custom validation, and I want to color the whole cell red if this validation fails. I think I am close to making it work, but not quite yet, and now I'm stumped.

My problem is that I cannot make the conditional (on validation fail) formatting work. The result is that the cells are correctly colored at the start, but when I insert a value that makes the falidating function return false, I get the usual red border, white background cell style.

How am I supposed to input this formatting style?

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
          <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
          <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"></Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  ...

  private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    foreach (DataGridTextColumn c in dg.Columns)
    {
      c.ElementStyle = (Style)dg.FindResource("s");

      for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
      {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        if (row == null) // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
        {
          dg.UpdateLayout();
          dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[i]);
          row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
        }
        TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)c.GetCellContent(row);

        Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(tb, TextBlock.TextProperty);
        binding.ValidationRules.Clear();
        binding.ValidationRules.Add(new VR());
      }
    }
  }
}

public class VR : ValidationRule
{
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

EDIT: updated XAML code according to dev hedgehog's suggestion, still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using ErrorTemplate wrong.

Take a look at this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
  <DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
  </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>


<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Age" Source="{StaticResource ods}"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <c:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Validation.ErrorTemplate will allow you to decorate AdornedElementPlaceholder which is in this case TextBox.

In the example I gave you a red ! will be decorated to the left of the TextBox.

**Edit:**

I changed your code to make it work.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" PreparingCellForEdit="OnBeginningEdit">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
                <DockPanel>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

This is the code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<D> Data { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Data = new List<D>();
        Random r = new Random();
        Data.Add(new D(r.NextDouble()));
        Data.Add(new D(r.NextDouble()));
        Data.Add(new D(r.NextDouble()));

        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridTextColumn c in dg.Columns)
        {
            c.EditingElementStyle = (Style)dg.FindResource("s");
        }
    }

    private void OnBeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tbx = (TextBox)e.EditingElement;
        Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(tbx, TextBox.TextProperty);
        binding.ValidationRules.Clear();
        binding.ValidationRules.Add(new VR());
    }
}
```

See you need to work with TextBoxes and when you write something inside one then click away in order to trigger validation.

Try it out. It works for me :)

Comment: This did not do anything for me. My columns are autogenerated so I'm not sure how to fit in the `Binding` part, but the validation code is called - and the error formatting is the default one - no red excalamation marks anywhere. It might have something to do with it being a DataGrid and not a TextBox. Anyway, I do not want to append TextBlocks for that reason either, I just want to give a custom format to the cell.

Comment: You want to give custom format for cell when cell is not valid anymore, right? Well use ErrorTemplate like I showed you just instead using TextBox type as in my example you should use DataGridCell type. The code I have you is an example and not something you should copy past to your project and it works just like that. :)

Comment: At the moment I'm using a TextBlock because that's what I can set in the code behind (c.ElementStyle property). I don't know how to apply styles to the cell, do I set Style in the AdornedElementPlaceholder? I tried that already but did not succeed. For that matter, I have not been able to apply any kind of custom change to my window on validation fail. It's always just the red border. I can't even get rid of that.

Comment: No, you do not set style on AdornedElementPlaceholder. You simply defined a style of TargetType DataGridCell and you place that style inside Window.Resource. That is how the style will be applied to cells. Cells are gonna look up for styles when generated and they are gonna find the style you will place in Window.Resources. It happens automatically as long you set the TargetType of the Style to DataGridCell.

Comment: I do not want the style to be applied automatically though, I want it to happen when validation fails. I am not able to give custom formattings on validation fail. Default formatting of elements, I can do.

Comment: The style we are talking about is called ErrorTemplate and if you do it the way I showed you with TextBox then it will be only applied when validation fails. When validation returns to valid the style will dissapear automatically. It is all happening automatically. Please create a demo and try it out simply with TextBox. Take the code I gave you and try it out. You will notice that ErrorTemplate will be displayed only when errors happen. Thats why it is called ErrorTemplate :)

Comment: I did it already. It's working perfectly with a single textbox that is not dynamically created. I want to do it with a DataGrid, and I can't.

Comment: Ahhh I see now your issue. NOOOPE my friend validation does not work when you update the target. Validation will only trigger when you update the source (...means to update a property in ViewModel). Validation does not work in both ways. It works only from target to source. By using TextBlock as target you do not have any updates to source. TextBlock is just displaying items but it is not changing them. You will need to use TextBox. When you start typing you will be changing the source and so you will trigger the ValidationRule and ErrorTemplate.

Comment: So, to make sure I understand this correctly: it is impossible to perform custom formatting on validation, because the DataGrid cell contains a TextBlock which is bad, while TextBox would be good. Is there a way to make the DataGrid use TextBoxes instead then?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible to perform validation when target lets say for example a TextBlock is being updated from the source lets say that is a property in ViewModel. Validation only works if target updates the source. That would be the case for example if you have TextBox as target. TextBox allows input and when text changed TextBox will first ask validation if valid and then it updates the source. If not valid the TextBox will display ErrorTemplate. This is how binding validation works. Are you asking for another validation?

Comment: Yes, I have to use a DataGrid in particular. I'm baffled at the fact that there is no easy way to restyle that red border I get when validation fails - it is so weird that I can perform my own validation on the field but I can't link my own style to it.

Comment: Could you upload your complete code on github.com or any other online storage site please. I need your code to follow you better :) Let me take a look at your code and then I ll solve it for you. It seems easier than this :)

Comment: The full XAML is now in the OP. The code behind is [here](http://pastebin.com/RrXp9v4W) and that would be the full project. I would just like to have a red background (or similar) on cells that do not validate according to my own validation rule. By the way, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I will take a look at it today and let you know about my progress.

Comment: I posted you the solution in my answer. Take a look at the edit

Comment: Thanks, I made it from there!